# Installing Swiss remote theme on Jekyll Github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm trying to use the Jekyll theme "Swiss" on my GitHub pages. Swiss (jekyll-swiss) is listed as an existing dependency at https://pages.github.com/versions/, and I think that even if it weren't I'd be allowed to use it with the jekyll-remote-theme gem. I followed the instructions on the Swiss repo (https://github.com/broccolini/swiss) for adding the theme to my Jekyll site:

```
Add this line to your Jekyll site's Gemfile:   
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugin

And add this line to your Jekyll site:  
remote_theme: broccolini/swiss
```

. . . and I also added the jekyll-remote-theme gem for good measure. I'm new to this, and can't figure out any other troubleshooting steps to take. Any ideas about why the theme isn't being applied to the site? My _config.yaml and Gemfile are below. Thanks in advance!

my _config.yml file:

```yml
name: Jekyll Test for Git Pages
markdown: kramdown
remote_theme: broccolini/swiss
theme_color: white
plugins:
  - jekyll-remote-theme
```

my Gemfile:

```ruby
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem "jekyll-remote-theme"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem(s):

1. I still had a _layouts/default.html file, which was overriding the Swiss theme's equivalent file.
2. My path file structure was odd. I had subfolders for pages and had index.html pages within the subfolders. This caused the theme styles and functionality to be applied inconsistently.